# How to replace wins 7 without disk - Hard drive failure

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, hard-drive-failure

My hard drive on my HP laptop has failed.  I do not have a install/backup disk.

How can I install windows 7 onto new hard drive without a disk?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **product key** in hand (it may be on a sticker on the bottom of the laptop or under the battery if it removable?) you can use [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) to download Windows 7 onto a media device, which can then be used to be put onto a hard drive.

Just follow the steps on that page.

Answer (score 0):

That's dependent on the licence type that HP used on your system. OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) Licences are normally restricted to images held by the OEM, meaning you can't go and download a random image from the internet and expect your key to work.

The best case scenario would be for you to obtain a copy of Windows 7 from HP support. However, they may charge to send you some bootable media.